# IntelliJ: disable voice/speech assistance

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-eap

As of IntelliJ version `135.666` speech/voice assistance has been added;
e.g. saying:

> awaiting orders
>
> work completed

Nice flashback to playing Star/War Craft; but could be annoying; especially to the co-workers

I would like to disable it; but couldn't find settings for it in the preferences panel.

p.s. Is this an April's fools joke (since it was released on April.1st)?

Comment: Switching back from EAP to "New Major Version Releases" channel helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's an April's Fools joke.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/04/where-is-intellij-idea-headed/

If you try to read through the comments of this post, you will surely figure out it's an April's Fools joke. :)